# Quicktime Skip after fast forward

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, quicktime

I'm running Mountain Lion on my Retina MBP and whenever I use Quicktime to fast-forward and then return to normal speed, the audio is skipped and doesn't work properly. The only fix I found(which isn't a fix) is to reopen the file, and not fast forward.

Have you encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a partial solution. As it appears, running 'purge' command from the terminal fixes the problem. This is not the ultimate solution(), but it gets the job done.

Also I should note that another fix might be to use CMD + T(Trim) - I've heard it helps, but I usually use Quicktime to watch videos online, which this feature is not available when streaming videos.

Cheers.